# Inverting diff() and BoxCox() in R

Tags: forecasting, arima, data-transformation, differences, boxcox-transformation

i'm doing a project with a non-stationary time series. i used BoxCox trasformation and differences to make it stationary

```
selling_boxcox<-BoxCox(selling,lambda=2)
selling_stationary<-diff(diff(selling_boxcox,lag=12,differences=1),differences=1)
```

and i've made this ARIMA model:

```
model<-arima(selling_stationary,order=c(1,1,1),seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,1),period=12),method="ML")
```

so i made forecasts using the forecast() function

```
selling_forecast<-forecast(model,h=60)
```

the only problem is that i need the forecasts on the original time series.
can i built a vector with the stationary series+forecasts and invert differences and BoxCox trasformation? how can i do it?

Answer (score 6):

This will do what you want:

```r
library(forecast)
model <- Arima(selling, order=c(1,1,1), seasonal=c(1,1,1), lambda = 2)
selling_forecast <- forecast(model, h=60)
```

- Note that `Arima` does the differencing and Box-Cox transformation for you and `forecast()` inverts both when computing forecasts.
- There is an `InvBoxCox()` function to invert a Box-Cox transformation if you really need to do it yourself.
- `lambda=2` is a strange choice. Normally you would use `lambda` between 0 and 1.